# Kloxo - Apache problems

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, lamp

I have recently installed kloxo and it has apache, however I have getting default page problems.

I have pointed my sub domain using "A-record" to the Apache server however I am either getting default page or "Internal Server Error 500". It's fresh installed I have not messed with the configurations.

I have commented out the "welcome.conf" however it leads me to the kloxo default page. I have tried commenting that out from the "httpd.conf". Basically this problem is spinning me in circles. I need help.

Here is my configs:

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

http://pastebin.com/U5FeC5G3

**/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost  \
          IP_Address:80\
                   >
#DocumentRoot /home/kloxo/httpd/default/
servername   default.*
ServerAlias   default.*
<Ifmodule mod_userdir.c>
Userdir "public_html"
</Ifmodule>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache error log:**

```
[Tue Jun 14 20:20:17 2011] [error] [client IP_Address] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup
[Tue Jun 14 20:20:53 2011] [error] [client IP_Address] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup
[Tue Jun 14 20:20:54 2011] [error] [client IP_Address] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup
[Tue Jun 14 20:20:55 2011] [error] [client IP_Address] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup
[Tue Jun 14 20:22:49 2011] [error] [client IP_Address] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup
[Tue Jun 14 20:22:51 2011] [error] [client IP_Address] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup
[Tue Jun 14 20:22:52 2011] [error] [client IP_Address] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup
```

Hope someone can help me out thanks.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At "Command Center" or in the shell (as root) run one at a time:

```
/script/fixweb
/script/fixphp
/script/upcp
```

Remember Kloxo latest version is 6.1.6. Check the version with /script/version or by clicking "Update Home" button in the web panel.